# Cubic gaussian instead of elliptic gaussian

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, gaussian, ellipse

I want to plot an ellipse modulated by a Gaussian like in the following example: https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/GAUSS2DFIT.html (see example then create an ellipse part)

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
B_max = 130
B_max2 = 120
theta = 80

x = np.linspace(-B_max*2,B_max*2,100)

XX,YY = np.meshgrid(x,x)

x_p = XX*np.cos(2*np.pi-np.deg2rad(theta))-YY*np.sin(2*np.pi-np.deg2rad(theta))
y_p = XX*np.sin(2*np.pi-np.deg2rad(theta))+YY*np.cos(2*np.pi-np.deg2rad(theta))

gaussian = np.exp(-((x_p/(B_max))**6+(y_p/(B_max2))**6)/2)


plt.figure()
plt.imshow(gaussian,extent =[-B_max*2,B_max*2,-B_max*2,B_max*2])

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(gaussian,extent =[-B_max*2,B_max*2,-B_max*2,B_max*2],norm=LogNorm(vmin=0.01, vmax=1))
```

However this is not the expect shape: I have more like a gaussian cube shape instead of the gaussian shape modulated by an ellipse. This looks like that the major axis and the minor axis lead the diagonal of the cube instead of being the limit of my ellipsoid shape. Am I doing something wrong with `meshgrid` ?

[image]

Comment: `np.random.multivariate_normal` might be better to generate elliptic Gaussian.

Comment: Thanks for this function but I can't get how can you use this function to generate a gaussian shape. For what I understood, this function will generate you random numbers inside according to a gaussian elliptical shape but this is not exactly what I want to do. I don't want to generate random point I want to make a map following this given shape.